# unknown column in field list - after site reverted to the older version

Tags: 6, database

I recently upgraded a site to Drupal 7 but decided to revert to Drupal 6.
Before I upgraded to Drupal 7 I did a database dump and back-up all files.
I've re-imported the database dump, deleted the Drupal 7 site and copied the Drupal 6 files back across.

Now I get the following errors

> Warning:  Unknown column 'headers' in 'field list'
>
> query: `SELECT data, created, headers, expire, serialized FROM cache
>   WHERE cid = 'variables'`

( and many more like this) and the column does actually exist in the database.

It eventually dies with:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function node_load() in
>   /var/www/html/includes/menu.inc on line

Comment: Did you import into a empty database, and did you copy the files to an empty directory? If not there might have been left-overs that cause issues. You could also try to manually empty the cache tables.

Comment: You definitely don't have a clean site if you have no node_load function. Also it's worth double checking you are using the database you think you're using. Sometimes it ends up being something really obvious. As mentioned by enzipher, if you are using the same database, you should drop it and re create it first, and make sure to delete old files first instead of just copying over the top.

Comment: exactly right rooby, I work in a large organisation and they gave me the wrong database... I have since been granted access to the correct one.